# Factoring code into a let block

Tags: let-binding

I'm following the instruction [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SetFonts) to set the default font:

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Monospace 10"))
(set-face-attribute 'default t :font "Monospace 10")
```

This works. To avoid the repetition, I tried factoring the string out with `let`:

```
(let ((f "Monospace 10"))
  (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . f))
  (set-face-attribute 'default t :font f))
```

The result I get when I load this is

> Invalid font: f

Why is the second expression not equivalent to the first pair of statements?

Comment: For reference about my background: I'm familiar with clojure, but obviously very new to elisp.

Comment: @npostavs Hm, I don't understand the connection between this question and that one. :(

Comment: The `'` is blocking evaluation of `f`, as explained in the answers on the linked question. `'(font . f)` == `(cons 'font 'f)`, but you want `(cons 'font f)` == `\`(font . ,f)`